# sending esp8266 random data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to connect to localhost mongoDB and send data from esp8266 to the mongoDB database. I want to send random data to the database. i have this code but unfortunately it is not connected. is it practically possible to approach it this way?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "ussd"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "password"

const char *mongoDBUser = "name";
const char *mongoDBPassword = "password";
const char *mongoDBServer = "localhost";
const int mongoDBPort = 27017; 
const char *dbName = "sensordb1";
const char *collectionName = "mycollection";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000); // Wait 5 seconds

  float randomTemperature = random(0, 100) / 10.0; // Generate a random temperature value

  WiFiClientSecure client;
  if (client.connect(mongoDBServer, mongoDBPort)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to MongoDB");

    // Prepare the JSON data to send
    String jsonData = "{\"sensor\": \"temperature\", \"value\": " + String(randomTemperature) + "}";

    // Build the POST request
    String request = "POST /" + String(dbName) + "/" + String(collectionName) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request += "Host: " + String(mongoDBServer) + "\r\n";
    request += "Authorization: Basic " + String(mongoDBUser) + ":" + String(mongoDBPassword) + "\r\n";
    request += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
    request += "Content-Length: " + String(jsonData.length()) + "\r\n";
    request += "\r\n";
    request += jsonData;

    client.print(request);
    while (client.connected()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      Serial.println(line);
    }
    Serial.println("Data sent to MongoDB");
    client.stop();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to MongoDB");
  }
}
```

Comment: "_but unfortunately it is not connected_" What, specifically, does that mean? What output and/or behavior(s) are you getting?

Comment: Serial.println("Failed to connect to MongoDB");

Comment: Well what's the reason/error reported for the connection failure? Not sure how we are supposed to try and help without troubleshooting information like that nor does your specific problem seem to have anything to do with 'sending esp8266 random data' at the moment, it's just about connecting to the database which there should be plenty of resources for

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" means what it says. It's a shorthand for "the same device". "localhost mongodb" in this case would mean "mongodb running on the ESP8266 that's trying to connect to it", which obviously is not happening.

You need to find out and use the correct name or IP address for the computer that's running MongoDB and that you're trying to connect to. It's not "localhost" and it's not "127.0.0.1".

How you find it depends very much on the computer running MongoDB. Searching the web should get you an answer for how to find the address. Then change your program to use the correct address rather than "localhost".

Comment: i adjusted the code and replaced the "localhost" with IP address of the computer hosting mongodb.   " IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.243"